# Tournament of 32 teams, 15 teams same country probability / odds

Tags: probability

Let's say there is a tournament with 32 teams, so there will be 16 matches in this round.

Let's say 15 teams are from the same country.

In this round, make one draw and What is the probability or odds that these 15 teams not draw with the team from the same country?

1st match draw - the odds of same country team of drawing team from same country = 15/32 = 0.47 (15 same country teams and 32 teams in total)
2nd match draw - 14/30 = 0.47 (14 same country teams and 30 teams remain in total)
3rd match draw - 13/28 = 0.46 (13 same country teams and 28 teams remain in total)

So on
12/26 = 0.46
11/24 =0.46
10/22 = 0.45
9/20 = 0.45
8/18 = 0.44
7/16 = 0.44
6/14 = 0.43
5/12 = 0.42
4/10 = 0.4
3/8 = 0.4
2/6 = 0.3
1/4 = 0.25

All these 15 probabilities multiply = 0.0000019073 (1 in 1000000)?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.

Comment: I read from the internet it should be some like 16/31 times 15/29...16 probabilities.  I don't know whether it's correct and how to multiple them.  That's why I ask to get some help

Comment: 16 matches in the first round ? Not meet in the first round ?

Comment: Yes, I got some help , is it 0.5^16=1/65536?  But I still dont know the step

Comment: @lulu what next?

Comment: @trueblueanil yes

Comment: Please edit your post to include your efforts.  It is not $.5^{16}$.  Why would you think that it was?

Comment: @lulu my attempt

Comment: I don't understand your computation.  Suppose the $15$ teams from country $X$ are $\{t_1, t_2, \cdots, t_{15}\}$.  The probability that $t_1$ is paired with a non-$X$ team is $\frac {17}{31}$.  After all, there are $32-15=17$ teams not from country $X$ and $31$ teams $t_1$ might be paired with.  Given that this has happened, the probability that $t_2$ is also not paired with a team from $X$ is then $\frac {16}{29}$ and so on.

Comment: @lulu I don't have a clue.  Your comment is helpful, using your method I got 0.000267767, 0.03%?

Comment: No....I get $\frac {17}{31}\times \frac {16}{29}\times \frac {15}{27}\times \cdots \times 1=0.000926758$

Comment: O I was wrong, I put 16/30 instead of 16/29, that's why

Comment: @lulu thank you very much for your help

Comment: @trueblueanil thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you saw on the internet (and have now included in your effort) is along the right lines but with wrong figures.

Imagine you are in one team (type $A$)along with $14$ other type $A$ teams from your country, and there are $17$ other teams (type $B$) from other countries.

P(your team doesn't meet with type $A) = \frac{17}{31}$, and so on,

so the ans should be $\frac{17}{31}\frac{16}{29}\frac{15}{27}...$

---

**Better Way**

Instead of doing such a long chain of multiplication, imagine $16$ blocks with two places in each block.

In order for the $15$ teams to not meet in first round, they must choose $15$ distinct blocks, and any of the two places in each block,

thus $Pr = \dfrac{\binom{16}{15}2^{15}}{\binom{32}{15}} = \dfrac{16384}{17678835} \approx 0.000927$

Comment: 0.000926758 =0.09%? =1 to 1079?

Comment: I have added a better way, yes calculator gives Pr = $1/1079$, *odds* $= 1:1078$